# Basic Exchange Site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, best-practices

I am a junior computer science major at Western Kentucky University. I want to make use of Stack Exchange and sites like it to let my future employers know that I know what I'm doing. Unfortunately I have realized that there is an almost vertical learning curve when starting out on this site.

Here are my reasons:

- I have owned a Stack Overflow account for months now and I can't build my reputation above 13
- There are so many people answering the easier questions that I know before I have the chance
- The questions that go through the general feed of 'new questions' or 'hot questions' are way over my head.
- When I do answer a question I have yet to get any credit for my contribution due to the negligence of the inquisitor to accept an answer.

What I'm suggesting is that there be a site for more basic questions. Maybe a Learning/Tutoring site where people who are asking more basic questions can have them answered by people who are closer to their level of knowledge.

This site would also give new Stack Overflow members a chance to get some reputation and learn how to tread water before having to jump into the ocean.

Ultimately I would like this site to do what I believe is the point of these Stack exchange sites. Make it easy to learn and share knowledge.

Does anyone have any advice or is there anybody who can make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), where you may start a proposal for a new Stack Exchange site with a subject of your choosing. That said, "StackOverflow but for more basic questions" is probably going to be a hard sell.

Comment: Thank you, I would give you a 1 up but..... yea ha ha